# RewriteRule just goes to 301 and not 404

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

RewriteRule applied only does 301 redirect and not 404 even though 404 is placed before 301.

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} =~ /abc(\.co)?\.in$/">
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/wp-content/uploads/01/(.*)$ - [L,R=404]
RewriteRule ^/wp-content/uploads/02/(.*)$ - [L,R=404]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://abc/ [QSD,L,R=301]
</If>
```

The expected result is to return 404 on all url's with wp-content/uploads/01 and 02 folders.

Currently, all the url's are returning 301 including the wp-content ones.
Not sure what is wrong.

do you think adding a conditional statement would help? but the problem here is there are other rules with many other if statements.

Comment: If you try `wp-content/uploads/01/` <-- note the `/` at the end, does it do the same thing?

Comment: Its the same as before. Yup still 301

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that it was a problem with RegEx. Needed to escape the forward slash.

```
^.*\/wp-content\/uploads\/(01|02)\/(.*) - [L,R=404]

https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/01/asd
```